# Demonstrate equalities are correct using trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

I got stuck with this specific problem, I tried from both sides but I cant get it.

$$\frac{\sin^3(x) + \cos^3(x)}{2 \sin^2(x) - 1} = \frac{\sec(x) - \sin(x)}{\tan(x) - 1}$$

P.S. This is my first post in this forum, sorry if I misspell something or used in a wrong way MathJax structure.

Maybe I must check StackExchange's English Q&A later. English is not my native language. Mathematics is a universal language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin^3 + \cos^3 = (\sin + \cos )(1 - \sin\cos), 2\sin^2 - 1= \sin^2-\cos^2 = (\sin - \cos)(\sin + \cos)\implies LHS = \dfrac{1-\sin\cos}{\sin - \cos}= RHS$ after dividing top and bottom by $\cos$.

Comment: Nice.
I realized that I could factorize using difference of cubes.

Step by step solution:

1.- (sin^3x+cos^3x) / (2sin^2x-1)
2.- (sinx+cosx)(sin^2x-sinxcosx+cos^2x) / (2sin^2x-(sin^2x+cos^2x))
3.- (sinx+cosx)(sin^2x-sinxcosx+cos^2x) / (sin^2x-cos^2x)
4.- (̶s̶i̶n̶x̶+̶c̶o̶s̶x̶)̶(sin^2x-sinxcosx+cos^2x) / (̶s̶i̶n̶x̶+̶c̶o̶s̶x̶)̶(sinx-cosx)
5.- (1-sinxcosx) / (sinx-cosx)
6.- Divide 5 by cosx

Thanks.